# Getting TPM's public EK: meaning of leading/trailing bits

Tags: cryptography, certificate, tpm

I have been trying to get a TPM's EK's public key using two methods:
using Hyper-V's `Get-PlatformIdentifier` I get the following result:

```
 3082010a0282010100<EKPUBLICKEY>0203010001
```

Using Urchin's C Library:

```
 <EKPUBLICKEY>
```

Can anyone explain what do `3082010a0282010100` and `0203010001` mean/encode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is DER Encoding of format for ASN.1 Types.

For example, `3082010A0282010100<KEY>0203010001`

`30`: said SEQUENCE type

`82010A`: Said SEQUENCE of length 010A (82 of which more than 80, indicates the length information of 2 bytes.)

`02`: Integer type

`820101`: An integer representing the length of 0101 (decimal 257)

`00<KEY>`: The integer is modulus, 00 used to denote a positive integer, deduct 00 and 256 bytes, so the modulus is 256 bytes

Finally Exponent

`0203010001`: 02 integer representing the length of 3010001 Exponent, 03